# How do we auto-verify an email address is Amazon SES using their API?

Tags: api, email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

Is there a way we can create a simple HTML button that on-click feeds an input email address (via a form field) to the Amazon SES API to verify a new address? Rather than having to manually login and verify people one by one in AWS?

Comment: Are you aware that  you can verify a whole domain at once? or are these users from multiple domains?

Comment: Yes multiple domains coming from mutiple users within a single web app

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/API_VerifyEmailIdentity.html

Answer (score 0):

You should only be sending out emails from one or a few domains. SES is set up to detect and minimise spam sources and you are fighting against it trying to send from numerous to/from addresses.

If you are collecting addresses, say from customers, and sending out email on their behalf (for example from a contact form), you should set the `From:` header to one of your verified domains and set the `Reply-To` header to the customer's address.

That way SES is happy that you are accurately identifying yourself as the source of the email but replies will go back to the customer.

Answer (score 0):

```
*You can use the aws sdk to invoke SES directly from code.Pass the list of email address to these lines of code.*

AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient ses= new AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient(credentials);

List lids = ses.listIdentities().getIdentities();
if (lids.contains(address)) {
    //the address is verified so            
      return true;
}
VerifyEmailAddressResult res = ses
            .verifyEmailAddress(new VerifyEmailAddressRequest().withEmailAddress(address));
    System.out.println("Please check the email address " + address + " to verify it");
```